# What is the mathematical basis of modulo fixed-point algorithm for IEEE 754 numbers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, floating-point, ieee-754

At the end of the question, an code for calculating floating modulo operation (`__ieee754_fmod` ) from GNU C library is presented. I'm interested in the basic ideas behind this algorithm.

Of particular interest is the code marked `/ * fix point fmod * /`.

```c
    /* fix point fmod */
    n = ix - iy;
    while(n--) {
        hz=hx-hy;
        if(hz<0){hx = hx+hx;}
        else {
            if(hz==0)                /* return sign(x)*0 */
                return Zero[(uint64_t)sx>>63];
            hx = hz+hz;
        }
    }
    hz=hx-hy;
    if(hz>=0) {hx=hz;}
```

1. How does fixed-point arithmetic apply to floating-point numbers?
2. How it can be changed to apply to floating-point numbers in decimal notation?
3. Does it have some common with this algorithm for finding the remainder ?

```
while(x >= y){
    auto scaled_y = y;
    while(scaled_y*2 < x)
        scaled_y *= 2;
    x -= scaled_y;
}
```

Simplified examples or links to detailed descriptions are encouraged.

From GNU C library [source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64/e_fmod.c.html):

```C
typedef union
{
    double value;
    struct
    {
        uint32_t lsw;
        uint32_t msw;
    } parts;
    uint64_t word;
} ieee_double_shape_type;


/* Get all in one, efficient on 64-bit machines.  */
#ifndef EXTRACT_WORDS64
# define EXTRACT_WORDS64(i,d)                                        \
do {                                                                \
  ieee_double_shape_type gh_u;                                        \
  gh_u.value = (d);                                                \
  (i) = gh_u.word;                                                \
} while (0)
#endif

/* Get all in one, efficient on 64-bit machines.  */
#ifndef INSERT_WORDS64
# define INSERT_WORDS64(d,i)                                        \
do {                                                                \
  ieee_double_shape_type iw_u;                                        \
  iw_u.word = (i);                                                \
  (d) = iw_u.value;                                                \
} while (0)
#endif


static const double one = 1.0, Zero[] = {0.0, -0.0,};
double __ieee754_fmod (double x, double y)
{
    int32_t n,ix,iy;
    int64_t hx,hy,hz,sx,i;
    EXTRACT_WORDS64(hx,x);
    EXTRACT_WORDS64(hy,y);
    sx = hx&UINT64_C(0x8000000000000000);        /* sign of x */
    hx ^=sx;                                /* |x| */
    hy &= UINT64_C(0x7fffffffffffffff);        /* |y| */
    /* purge off exception values */
    if(__builtin_expect(hy==0
                        || hx >= UINT64_C(0x7ff0000000000000)
                        || hy > UINT64_C(0x7ff0000000000000), 0))
        /* y=0,or x not finite or y is NaN */
        return (x*y)/(x*y);
    if(__builtin_expect(hx<=hy, 0)) {
        if(hx<hy) return x;        /* |x|<|y| return x */
        return Zero[(uint64_t)sx>>63];        /* |x|=|y| return x*0*/
    }
    /* determine ix = ilogb(x) */
    if(__builtin_expect(hx<UINT64_C(0x0010000000000000), 0)) {
        /* subnormal x */
        for (ix = -1022,i=(hx<<11); i>0; i<<=1) ix -=1;
    } else ix = (hx>>52)-1023;
    /* determine iy = ilogb(y) */
    if(__builtin_expect(hy<UINT64_C(0x0010000000000000), 0)) {        /* subnormal y */
        for (iy = -1022,i=(hy<<11); i>0; i<<=1) iy -=1;
    } else iy = (hy>>52)-1023;
    /* set up hx, hy and align y to x */
    if(__builtin_expect(ix >= -1022, 1))
        hx = UINT64_C(0x0010000000000000)|(UINT64_C(0x000fffffffffffff)&hx);
    else {                /* subnormal x, shift x to normal */
        n = -1022-ix;
        hx<<=n;
    }
    if(__builtin_expect(iy >= -1022, 1))
        hy = UINT64_C(0x0010000000000000)|(UINT64_C(0x000fffffffffffff)&hy);
    else {                /* subnormal y, shift y to normal */
        n = -1022-iy;
        hy<<=n;
    }
    /* fix point fmod */
    n = ix - iy;
    while(n--) {
        hz=hx-hy;
        if(hz<0){hx = hx+hx;}
        else {
            if(hz==0)                /* return sign(x)*0 */
                return Zero[(uint64_t)sx>>63];
            hx = hz+hz;
        }
    }
    hz=hx-hy;
    if(hz>=0) {hx=hz;}
    /* convert back to floating value and restore the sign */
    if(hx==0)                        /* return sign(x)*0 */
        return Zero[(uint64_t)sx>>63];
    while(hx<UINT64_C(0x0010000000000000)) {        /* normalize x */
        hx = hx+hx;
        iy -= 1;
    }
    if(__builtin_expect(iy>= -1022, 1)) {        /* normalize output */
        hx = ((hx-UINT64_C(0x0010000000000000))|((uint64_t)(iy+1023)<<52));
        INSERT_WORDS64(x,hx|sx);
    } else {                /* subnormal output */
        n = -1022 - iy;
        hx>>=n;
        INSERT_WORDS64(x,hx|sx);
        x *= one;                /* create necessary signal */
    }
    return x;                /* exact output */
}
```

Comment: If you want to discuss anything except macros, better make a [mre] without macros.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. How does fixed-point arithmetic apply to floating-point numbers?

See below:

```
    /* fix point fmod */
```

At this point, I presume (having not examined the prior code thoroughly) `ix` and `iy` are the floating-point exponents of the inputs `x` and `y`, `hx` and `hy` are their significands, and |`y`| ≤ |`x`|. The comment “fix point fmod” refers to the fact that this code is working on the significands of the floating-point numbers. However, that is an inapt description; it is not truly a fixed-point `fmod`, because it does use the exponents to do some scaling, as we will see.

```
    n = ix - iy;
```

This sets `n` to the difference in the exponents.

```
    while(n--) {
```

This starts a loop dealing with the different scaling of the numbers due to the exponents.

```
        hz=hx-hy;
```

This performs a trial subtraction; after testing the sign, we might or might not use this result. Note that, regardless of the difference in exponents between `x` and `y`, `hy` is **some** multiple of `y` relative to `hx`. That is, even though the significands might not be aligned for a normal subtraction, the number represented by `hz` has the same residue modulo `y` that the number represented by `hx` does, since all numbers that differ by a multiple of `y` have the same residue.

```
        if(hz<0){hx = hx+hx;}
```

If `hz` is negative, we do not want to deal with `hx-hy` yet. Instead, `hx` is shifted left one bit, moving its scaling more toward that of `hy`. (Recall we are in a loop on `n`, so, ultimately, shifting `hx` left `n` bits will put `hx` and `hy` on the same scale.)

```
        else {
            if(hz==0)                /* return sign(x)*0 */
                return Zero[(uint64_t)sx>>63];
            hx = hz+hz;
        }
```

If `hz` is zero, we haven proven `x` is a multiple of `y`, so the residue is zero, and that is returned, with an appropriate sign bit. Otherwise, `hz` is positive. In this case, `hx = hz+hz;` does two things: First, it replaces `hx` with `hz`, which is a valid substitution because `hx` and `hz` have the same residue modulo `y`, but `hz` is smaller, so we have reduced it somewhat. Second, it shifts `hx` left one bit, preparing us for the next loop iteration.

```
    }
```

This continues iterating on `n`.

```
    hz=hx-hy;
```

This is another trial subtraction; after testing the sign, we might or might not use the result. At this point, `hx` has been reduced modulo `y` by the preceding loop, and we are testing to see whether one final subtraction is needed or we are done.

```
    if(hz>=0) {hx=hz;}
```

If `hz` is less than zero, the loop completely reduced `hx`; it produced a residue less than `hy`, and we are done: `hx` contains the residue to use. If `hz` is greater than or equal to zero, `hx` was not completely reduced, so we replace it by `hz`, we contains `hx` reduced by subtracting `hy`. This is the final subtraction needed—we know there are no more because we are working in binary and the leading bit of `hy` is set due to normalization, so `hx/hy` must be less than two, which then implies `hx-hy < hy`, and the goal of `fmod` is to produce a residue less than |`y`|.

> 2. How it can be changed to apply to floating-point numbers in decimal notation?

The algorithm would have to be rewritten considerably to apply to floating-point numbers. In particular, the code above relies on binary in that only one subtraction is needed at each step; the integer part of the quotient `hx`/`hy` is always 0 or 1. With a decimal representation, accommodation would have to be made for the fact that the integer part of the quotient could range from 0 to 9, so various multiples of `hy` would have to be subtracted.

> 3. Does it have some common with this algorithm for finding the remainder ?
>
> ```
> while(x >= y){
>     auto scaled_y = y;
>     while(scaled_y*2 < x)
>         scaled_y *= 2;
>     x -= scaled_y;
> ```

Some. That code also subtract multiples of `y` from `x`, for the purpose of reducing `x` modulo `y`.